Git ignore obj / debug folder after using git init
I have some existing code but now want to push this to GIT so I followed some steps and it states
cd <localdir>
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git remote add origin <url>
git push -u origin main

I do jus that but I want to omit the obj and debug folders for example however when I try to this my pending committed files do not change.
I am little confused as to why its not respecting my ignore file? I must be doing something silly but not sure what


Your gitignore file does not contain an entry for debug. bin and obj should already be picked up. Note that gitignore does not ignore tracked files. You did git add ., so all files are tracked. You can only ignore untracked files

You have to append a / to folders to ignore:
bin/
obj/
debug/
packages/


The problem is that the files are already tracked. You cannot ignore tracked files

To untrack them you have to issue git rm --cached <FILES> and a commit.

You need to exclude all files and directories inside obj and debug folder by adding "/**"
obj/**
debug/**


The trailing slash is enough.

@AntonioPetricca /** also would work on untracked files.
